# REST API subresource design

Tags: rest, api

Consider the classic posts and comments example, where the sub-resource design suits best: 
`/posts/<id>/comments`
But if I also want to have an endpoint to get all comments from all posts (for example for review and supervising) what can I do?

Separate paths like `/posts` and `/comments` can work but maybe between many resources separate `/comments` doesn't make much sense.

Is a endpoint like `posts/comments [GET]` against guidelines?